# .click() affect only one element with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got the list of news, with short and full text, and a title of the news article. Clicking on it expands full view and vise versa. Yet clicking on first article also expands all other articles. How do I only affect the one I clicked?

Here's the [example](http://jsbin.com/irihax/1/edit):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.news-expand').click(function () {
        $(".news-content-short").toggle();
        $(".news-content-full").toggle();
        $('.news-date').toggleClass('active-date');
        $('.news-expand').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to act on only the items in the section you clicked. The code for that would be like:

```
$(document)
    .ready(function () {
    $('.news-expand')
        .click(function () {
        var par = $(this).parents('.main-news-holder');
        par.find(".news-content-short").toggle();
        par.find(".news-content-full").toggle();
        par.find('.news-date').toggleClass('active-date');
        par.find('.news-expand').toggleClass('active');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Check this **demo:** http://jsbin.com/ikijap/1/edit

Comment: Actually, You're better off using closest, instead of parents. Else you're using a function that was intended to do more than you're using it for.

Comment: .click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 4):

You're problem is not that your click event is called based on class, but that in your click event you're acting on every item in the class.

Instead, use [this](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/)

For more details on the click event, see [JQuery's API](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are always working on **all** items of the set. So e.g. `$(".news-content-short").toggle();` toggles all items with the according class and not only the one you want.

The following should work:

```
$('.news-expand').click(function () {
      $parent = $(this).parents(".main-news-holder");
      $parent.find(".news-content-short,.news-content-short").toggle().end()
             .find('.news-date').toggleClass('active-date').end()
             .find('.news-expand').toggleClass('active');
});
```

**[Your example working](http://jsbin.com/irihax/20/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document)
    .ready(function () {
    $('.news-expand').click(function () {
        var parent = $(this).closest('.main-news-holder');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        parent.find(".news-content-short").toggle();
        parent.find(".news-content-full").toggle();
        parent.find('.news-date').toggleClass('active-date');
    });
});
```

Comment: actually, you have to go `$(this).parent().parent().parent()` ^^

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get to the parent div and after that you can hide/show the correct divs.
Check the jsbin demo here: http://jsbin.com/irihax/14/

```
$(document)
    .ready(function () {
    $('.news-expand')
        .click(function () {
          var mainDiv = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
        mainDiv.find(".news-content-short").toggle();
        mainDiv.find(".news-content-full").toggle();
        mainDiv.find('.news-date').toggleClass('active-date');
        mainDiv.find('.news-expand').toggleClass('active');
    });

});
```

Comment: Using the parents function provided by @techfoobar is better.

Answer (score 0):

By rearrange the html code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>JS Bin</title>
        <script>
$(document)
    .ready(function () {
    $('.news-header')
        .click(function () {
        $(this).children('div').toggle();
    });
});
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="main-news">
            <div class="main-news-holder">
                <div class="news-date">
                    <p>1 sep</p>
                </div>
                <div class="news-header" style="border:1px solid;">
                    <p><a class="news-expand" href="#">Show more</a></p>
                    <div class="news-content-short">
                    <p>short short short short short</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="news-content-full" style="display: none;">
                        <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
                            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
                            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
                            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
                            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
                            text text text text text text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- ################################################################################################################################
            -->
            <div class="main-news-holder">
                <div class="news-date">
                    <p>2 sep</p>
                </div>
                <div class="news-header">
                    <p><a class="news-expand" href="#">Show more</a></p>
                    <div class="news-content-short">
                    <p>short short short short short</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="news-content-full" style="display: none;">
                        <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
                            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
                            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
                            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
                            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
                            text text text text text text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Hope this will help.