# Affect only element that is clicked in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have div with same class. When I click on box-one arrow, I want to slide box-two. Problem is because I have five boxes with same class and when I click on one it opens all boxes. How to affect click on arrow to open only box that is clicked?  Anyone can help?

```
<div class="box-one">
<a href="#" class="arrow"></a>
</div> 
<div class="box-two">
<p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div class="box-one">
<a href="#" class="arrow"></a>
</div> 
<div class="box-two">
<p>Some text</p>
</div>

.box-two { display: none; }

$('.box-one a.arrow').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ('.box-two').slideToggle(300);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.click() affect only one element with class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973811/click-affect-only-one-element-with-class)

Answer (score 1):

You use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to find just the `.box-one` containing the arrow that was clicked, then use [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next) to affect only the `.box-two` that follows that `.box-one`:

```
$(".box-one a.arrow").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".box-one").next().slideToggle(300);
});
```

**Live Example:**

```js
$(".box-one a.arrow").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".box-one").next().slideToggle(300);
});
```

```css
.box-two { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="box-one">
<a href="#" class="arrow">arrow</a>
</div> 
<div class="box-two">
<p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div class="box-one">
<a href="#" class="arrow">arrow</a>
</div> 
<div class="box-two">
<p>Some text</p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

More to explore: [The traversing category of the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) *(actually, the entire API docs only take an hour or so to read)*.